# Importing MIDI into Reason 5

Tags: midi

I have just upgraded from Reason 3 to Reason 5 (I know, I'm behind the times but I like programs that work).

In Reason 3, I would import a MIDI file (which I create with an external sequencer) then create instruments. Then I would assign the tracks to instruments. Should I need to change the tracks (a frequent need!), I could delete the tracks without deleting the instruments. After reimporting the MIDI file, I would again assign the tracks to the already existing instruments.

In Reason 5, importing a MIDI file causes a combinator to be created automatically for every track. I can set up the combinators or replace them directly with other instruments. Should I wish to change the tracks, I can delete them without deleting the instruments, but when I reimport the MIDI, new combinators are created.

How I can assign the tracks to the already existing instruments?

Answer (score 1):

You can move-it by drag and drop sequencer clips between tracks. Use "Song Position Pointer tool" to set start point of clips that you wanna move in the beginning of clip.